# Bloquear fechas vencidas en un input type datetime

Tags: php, javascript, html

¿Cómo puedo bloquear las anteriores con el `min` pero que la fecha sea la del día de hoy y no un valor puesto a mano?

```html
<label for="start">Dia y horario de consulta:</label><br>
<input type="Datetime-local" min="2020-05-26T14:00" name="start" id="start" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando `Javascript` podrías:

- Crear un objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date).
- Obtener la fecha en foramto ISO ([`.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/toISOString))
- Y establecer esta cadena como valor de la propiedad `min` del `input`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let start = document.getElementById('start');
start.min = (new Date()).toISOString().substr(0, 19);
```

```html
<label for="start">Dia y horario de consulta:</label><br>
<input type="Datetime-local" name="start" id="start" />
```

---

Usando `PHP` podrias:

- Imprimir la fecha usando [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) y el formato `c` (*Fecha ISO 8601*)

#### Ejemplo:

```
<label for="start">Dia y horario de consulta:</label><br>
<input type="Datetime-local" min="<?php echo substr(date('c'), 0, 19) ?>" name="start" id="start" />
```

Comment: El problema de esta solución es que se ajustará a la zona horaria GMT y no a la correspondiente del cliente. De todos modos asignarle el valor correcto a `start.min` es la solución (o insertarla con PHP también)

Comment: @Japsz, en realidad depende de la implementación que se le quiera dar, ya que si usa la opción `JS` la fecha obtenida estará basada en la configuración del cliente, en cambio usando la opción `PHP` la fecha obtenida estará basada en la configuración del servidor.

Comment: creo estar seguro que el método `.toISOString()` siempre retorna la hora sin retraso con respecto a UTC (+00:00), independiente de la zona horaria del cliente. En `PHP` no estoy seguro pues no tengo tantas horas en tal lenguaje. La solución es la correcta de todos modos! sólo hay que tener ojo en el valor a ponerle

Comment: Muchas gracias, ambas soluciones me sirvieron pero por alguna razón al seleccionar la fecha en el input no se guardan los cambios, y al mandar los datos detecta que el input está vacío, qué puede ser?